# Flutter Web Http not working on web Browser

Tags: flutter, web

Greeting
I have a Flutter app and it calls HTTP (when I try to call the HTTP )on mobile and desktop it works perfectly but when I try the same app the same code on the web always gets an error, I also tried Dio and the same problem occurs. so it's not a code problem
The error message I am getting in Dio

> DioException [connection error]: The connection errored: The
> XMLHttpRequest onError callback was called. This typically indicates
> an error on the network layer

even the simple sample of dio is not working

```
void main() async {
  final dio = Dio();
  final response = await dio.get('https://pub.dev');
  print(response.data);
}
```

if I run it on   Windows app or mobile (Android) it works perfect
any suggestions plz

Comment: This will be a CORS error. Open the browser's Dev Tools > Network tab to confirm.

Answer (score -1):

Be very careful when calling **async** functions.

Async means you have to wait for the result, meaning, if you try to use its response immediately, you might get an error, because the response doesn't exist yet.

The best way to work with async calls is to use a **callback**, that executes the code you need after you get the response.

You can also create a **FutureBuilder** that only draws when the **response**.

Or you might create a `try { ...  } catch(e){ ... }` to ensure that there is no error when trying to read the response, and only when the response is valid, it builds the widget.